# C++ - Boolean operation

Tags: c++, variables, visual-c++, input, boolean

I have this (I've just started to learn btw):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{

string mystr;
cout << "Welcome, what is your name? ";
getline(cin, mystr);
cout << "Nice to meet you, " << mystr << endl;
cout << "May i call you 1 for short? (y/n)" << endl;
getline(cin, mystr);
}
```

I want to next say;

```
cout << "Thank you, 1" << endl;
```

OR:

```
cout << "Well ok, " << mystr << endl;
```

... based on whether or not the user has typed y or n. How would i go about this? I've had a look around but i don't really know how to word it. I'm using Visual Studio Express and it is a console application.

Comment: Have you ever heard of the `if` statement?

Comment: I was thinking it would be something like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a very simple way:

```
if (mystr == "1") {
    // ...
}
```

But you should accustom yourself to more error checking, so check the state of the stream after `getline`:

```
getline(cin, mystr);
if (cin) {
    if (mystr == "1") {
        // ...
    }
} else {
    // error
}
```

And of course, you may want to support any number in the future, not just 1. Then you need to convert the input string to a number. See [`std::stoi`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol) if you use C++11, or look at the thousands of past Stackoverflow questions about string-to-number conversions :)

---

**Edit**: Just noticed that you actually wanted to check for "y". Well, that's the same then:

```
if (mystr == "y") {
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use if-else statement. For example

```
#include <cctype>

//...

std::string name = mystr;

std::cout << "May i call you 1 for short? (y/n)" << std::endl;
std::getline( std::cin, mystr );

for ( char &c : mystr ) c = std::tolower( c );

if ( mystr == "y" )
{
   name = "1";
   std::cout << "Thank you, " << name << std::endl;
}
else
{
   std::cout << "Well ok, " << name << std::endl;
}
```